# How to draw a better looking Graph (A4 size) in Dot?

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I have this project that it's due in a few hours and I still have a report to write... The project has nothing to do with Dot, but we were asked to draw a Graph with Dot, which I did.

It looks something like this:
http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/9735/dotj.jpg

The longer arrows represent smaller weights and the shorter arrows represent bigger weights. There isn't any problem in submitting my project like this, it does what's is supposed to do and this Dot thing is just an extra.

But I would like to make it pretty, I just don't have time to learn about Dot right now. Basically, all I want is make pretty. Perhaps, a bigger height for the page, like A4 paper size. And have the graph display more to the bottom than everything to the side.

What should I put on my .dot file to make it look better?

Comment: As it stands, that presentation is a very poor visualization of what you are trying to communicate. Tufte would say "use a table" given how simple the relations between the entities are. Post your dot code and I'd take a stab at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of options that can help to fix this problem. Setting the `size` option to be whatever the dimensions of an A4 sheet of paper are would be a good start. The GraphViz guide goes over most of the relevant options pretty thoroughly (see page 14 of [this pdf](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/dotguide.pdf), it's not as long as it looks, only 2 or 3 pages for the relevant info).

Comment: Dont exist the file.